# Setting Event Handler in WPF code behind

Tags: wpf, xaml

My WPF program uses a third party map package which has a WPF map control.  My program needs to be able to run on a system which does not have this software installed, and it needs to be smart enough to recognize when the software is installed and use it.  This means that I can't include any XAML for the map control in my form's XAML file or XAML parse exceptions are thrown.

I have a technique for determining if the software is installed.  In my program's initialization code, I set a property of the Application object called `MapsAreInstalled` to true if the mapping software is installed, and I set it to false if it is not.

In my form, which is a UserControl, I've added an override of the OnApplyTemplate method.  This checks the value of the `MapsAreInstalled` property and creates a new map control if the value is true.  Here's the XAML that I was using to create this control before it became obvious that I had to change my approach:

```
<telogis:MapControl ButtonBase.Click="CarImage_Click"
                    Canvas.Left="0"
                    Canvas.Top="0"
                    Center="41.366674544084,-73.6112966322899"
                    DragBehavior="None"
                    Heading="0"
                    Height="{Binding ElementName=ChannelCanvas, Path=ActualHeight}"
                    MapQuality="Perfect"
                    Name="ReadMap"
                    Perspective="TwoD"
                    RenderLabels="True"
                    UiEnable="True"
                    Width="{Binding ElementName=ChannelCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}"
                    Zoom="50" />
```

I know how to initialize all of these properties in the code behind EXCEPT the `ButtonBase.Click` event handler.  How do I set this up in the code-behind?

Tony

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer to this one:

```
RoutedEventHandler clickHandler = MyClickHandler;
mapCtrl.AddHandler( ButtonBase.ClickEvent, clickHandler );
```

Thanks anyway.